# How to call <script src> from a relative page

Tags: javascript, html, src

i have 2 pages:

**HOME** page with span element:

```
<span id="t1"></span>
<span id="t2"></span>
```

**TEST** page with js:

```
<script>
const data = {
"t1": 'value1',
"t2": 'value2',
}
Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => {
const span = document.getElementById(k);
if (span) span.innerHTML = v;
})
</script>
```

Due to technical limitation i can't create a .js file and call for it from HOME page and i need to use the same script from TEST page on HOME page without copy-pasting it.

Is it possible to call for the script **without .js file** from HOME page in a way similar to this:

**HOME** with a src path to **TEST** page script:

```
<span id="t1"></span>
<span id="t2"></span>

<script src="https://website.com/TEST"></script>
```

Tried but failed to have a result.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer depends on you answering WHY you cannot create a script file but CAN include a script tag that tries to load an html page

Comment: What `technical limitation`?  If the **Home** page can't load it directly using a `script` tag in the `head` section, how could it load it via a script tag in the `body` section?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you could use a Server Side Script like php

convert test.js to test.php with 
and include it to your home.php

.php extensions parse HTML as normal .html pages but you can perform stuff like include 'test.php' with that too, giving you more control, you dont need to copy paste the code ass the time just include the .php file.

if you want to stick with html, javscript, its a no as you need a reference to what you need to accomplish via javascript that can be on the same page or if its on another page you need to have a reference.